# Can a model belong to either one of two other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I will try to explain this as best as I can.

I have 3 models.

DistributionEvent
PrimaryAssignment
SecondaryAssignment

I need the **DistributionEvent** to belong_to either a **PrimaryAssignment** or a **SecondaryAssignment** and show on the same column in the database.

So something like this

```
class DistributionEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :primaryassignment
 belongs_to :secondaryassignment
end

class PrimaryAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :distribution_event
end

class SecondaryAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :distribution_event
end
```

But the DistributionEvent should only have one column (assignment or something) in the table that points to either primaryassignments or secondaryassignments.

I hope that make sense.

Anyone have any clue on how to achieve this efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: Why it has to be only one column? I guess it is the foreign id column.

Comment: I guess it really doesn't have to be, but I assumed that be the most logical way since every DsitributionEvent row has to have either a PrimaryAssignment or SecondaryAssignment. That would prevent from having two columns and having one of them blank on every entry.

Comment: Then I guess the answer from @panmari is the conventional way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with polymorphic associations. The documentation can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

```
class DistributionEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :assignment, polymorphic: true
end

class PrimaryAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :distribution_events, as: :assignment
end

class SecondaryAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :distribution_events, as: :assignment
end
```

Make sure to also add a column for the type:

```
class AddAssignmentTypeToDistributionEvent < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :distribution_events, :assignment_type, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: That is two columns, no?

Comment: It fulfills the 'one-column' requirement as it does only allow one single assignment to be associated with each distribution event. But yes, it does use two columns in the database.

Comment: Why someone would give minuses for an answer, which could be an option. Especially, since the question did not specify all the conditions and constrains...

Comment: Because when I looked at the answer it was just a link to the guide page for polymorphic associations which didn't seem like a very useful answer - and indeed I was about to flag it when it was edited dramatically.

Comment: @Shadwell: Ok, now I see from where and for what reason all those minuses are coming from. So you think the description in the question is not sufficient enough to understand where the source/link is pointing to? Besides, it looks like that guys was in a harry, and also added his code later, but have you removed your minus?

Comment: @Gen I think the question is fine, and upvoted it. 

I haven't removed my minus as it was valid at the time of voting. Removing it rewards people who post a poor answer to get in quick and only then spend some time to post a better answer.

Comment: @Shadwell: well, probably it is fair. Thanks for letting me know about all this. At least now I know what to expect.

Comment: This looks what I need. I'll try it out in a second and see if it's it.

Comment: I ended up implementing this and it was just what I needed. Thanks!